# What is the difference between a three month return and a quarterly return?

Tags: finance, mutual-fund, earnings

I am looking at VGENX, and this product has first-quarter and three-month returns of 7.8% and 20.3%, respectively, according to zacks.com. I take it as the three month return is calculated taking into account the three months from a given time, (which is now) - so march, feb and jan - which is essentially the same as Q1. How come is it that the difference is so dramatic and how exactly do we calculate these indicators?

Comment: According to Bloomberg the return for first Quarter 2016 for VGENX is 7.8159% which matches your value. The return from 1/11/2016 to 4/11/2016 is 19.73% which is close but not identical to your second value. Basically the retn for 1st 10 days of year was extremely poor and that for most recent 10 days extremely good.